# Using stringstream to input/output a bool value

Tags: c++, stringstream

this may seem like a stupid question but i am stumped. Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    string line, command;
    getline(cin, line);
    stringstream lineStream(line);

    bool active;
    lineStream >>active;
    cout <<active<<endl;

}
```

no matter what i input for active, it always prints out 0. so lets say my input was

```
true
```

it would output 0 and same thing for false.

Comment: IIRC `bool` is treated special when parsing, there's some stream manipulator to control how it's parsed. Default is looking up for `0` and `1`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should always verify if your input was successful: you'll find it was not. You want to try the value `1` with your current setup:

```
if (lineStream >> active) {
    std::cout << active << '\n';
}
else {
    std::cout << "failed to read a Boolean value.\n";
}
```

If you want to be able to enter `true` and `false`, you'll need to use `std::boolalpha`:

```
if (lineStream >> std::boolalpha >> active) {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << active << '\n';
}
```

The formatting flag changes the way `bool` is formatted to use locale-dependent strings.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the `boolalpha` manipulator.

```
lineStream >> boolalpha >> active;
cout << boolalpha << active << endl;
```

By default, streams input and output `bool` values as tiny numbers.  `boolalpha` tells the stream to instead use the strings "true" and "false" to represent them.

Answer (score 1):

for `ostringstream`:

```
ostringstream& writeBool(ostringstream& oss, bool val)
{
    oss << std::boolalpha << val;

    return oss;
}
```

for `istringstream`:

```
bool readBool(std::istringstream& iss)
{

    bool readVal(false);

    iss >> std::boolalpha >> readVal;

    return readVal;
}
```